# Equi program on Codility

Tags: c#, .net

Has anyone tried the Equi demo program on Codility using `C#` on `.NET 2.0`?
I ran my solution and it gave an error,

> user.cs(25,9): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Solution'
>   could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?

To test the compiler, I just ran a blank script next. I get the same error as above. Is this a fault with their compiler?

Comment: Sounds like forget to use proper using directive or assembly (as error said). Would be better if we see code or something..

Comment: @SonerGönül But it gives the same error when i run a blank. Shouldn't a blank execute normally without errors?

Comment: You have a problem with the setup of your solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {

        // first compute the sum of the array, put in second half sum.
        int firstsum = 0;
        int secondsum = 0;

        foreach (int num in A)
        {
            secondsum += num;
        }

        // kepp an index 
        int index = 0;

        while ( index <= A.Length -1 )
        {
            secondsum -= A[index];

            if (secondsum == firstsum)
            {
                return index;
            }

            firstsum += A[index];
            ++ index;
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

This solution does not work 100% for extremely large/negative values. But this is what I came up with during the sample test.

Answer (score 0):

Use long datatype and it will get 100 score

```
long firstsum = 0;
long secondsum = 0;
```